# In Java how to simplify using multilevel nested static class name when creating objects in outer class?

Tags: java, import, inner-classes

In Java how to simplify using multilevel nested static class, in delcaration statements( like LinkedList.Node in below code), when creating objects in outerclass  ? 
I want to use something like "import static" statement so that I can avoid using long declaration statements. Please suggest.
I tried import statement like "import static LinkedListTechniques.LinkedList.*". But it is showing error - "The import LinkedListTechniques cannot be resolved".

```
public class LinkedListTechniques {

    public static class LinkedList {

        private Node head;

        public static class Node {
            private Node next;
            private int value;

            public Node() {
                this.next = null;
                this.value = -1;
            }

            public Node(int value, Node next) {
                this.next = next;
                this.value = value;
            }

            public Node getNext() {
                return next;
            }

            public void setNext(Node next) {
                this.next = next;
            }

            public int getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            public void setValue(int value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

        }

        public LinkedList() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public LinkedList(Node head) {
            super();
            this.head = head;
        }

        public Node getHead() {
            return head;
        }

        public void setHead(Node head) {
            this.head = head;
        }

    }

    public static void insertAtEnd(LinkedList list, int element) {

        if (list.getHead() == null) {
            list.setHead(new LinkedList.Node(element, null));
            return;
        }
        LinkedList.Node current = list.getHead();

        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }

        LinkedList.Node newNode = new LinkedList.Node(element, null);
        current.next = newNode;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: "it is showing error". Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Don't create so many nested classes.

Comment: @Stultuske Added error message.

Comment: @Kayaman yes, but what if we have such set of nested classes. Any convinient solution? Interested to see if there is some solution available.

Comment: The solution is not to create such problems for yourself. For example in this case the `LinkedList` and `Node` class should definitely **not** be inside `LinkedListTechniques` class. The `insertAtEnd` method is completely wrong, it should be an instance method of `LinkedList` and not take `LinkedList` as a parameter. Your question isn't about a real problem, it's just due to your bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Is your class `LinkedListTechniques` in the default package? If this is the case it won't be possible to use static import. Try to move it to a package and you'll be able to do what you want.

For example, I created a package `example` and created these classes inside:

LinkedListTechniques.java

```
package example;
public class LinkedListTechniques {
    public static class LinkedList {
        public static class Node {}
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package example;
import example.LinkedListTechniques.LinkedList.Node;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node node = new Node();
    }
}
```

and it compiled without errors.